# Combining multiple signal not working using Reactive Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I am following this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/62699/reactivecocoa-tutorial-pt1. It is working for username and password field.

I am trying to create sign up form which contains three fields: email, password, confirmPassword.

I have validated email address (working perfectly)
I have validated password like this:

password should be at least 6 characters and both password and confirmPassword must be same.

Here is my code:

```
RACSignal *validEmailSignal =
[emailTextField.rac_textSignal
 map:^id(NSString *text) {
     return @([text isValidEmailAddress]);
 }];

RACSignal *validPasswordSignal =
[passwordTextField.rac_textSignal
 map:^id(NSString *text) {
     return @([text isEqualToString:self.confirmPasswordTextField.text] && text.length >5);
 }];

RACSignal *validConfirmPasswordSignal =
[confirmPasswordTextField.rac_textSignal
 map:^id(NSString *text) {
     return @([text isEqualToString:self.passwordTextField.text] && text.length >5 );
 }];

[[validEmailSignal
  map:^id(NSNumber *emailValid) {
      return [emailValid boolValue] ? [UIColor greenColor] : [UIColor redColor];
  }]
 subscribeNext:^(UIColor *color) {
     emailTextField.layer.borderColor=[color CGColor];
     emailTextField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

 }];

[[validPasswordSignal
  map:^id(NSNumber *passwordValid) {
      return [passwordValid boolValue] ? [UIColor greenColor] : [UIColor redColor];
  }]
 subscribeNext:^(UIColor *color) {
     passwordTextField.layer.borderColor=[color CGColor];
     passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
     confirmPasswordTextField.layer.borderColor=[color CGColor];
     confirmPasswordTextField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
 }];

[[validConfirmPasswordSignal
  map:^id(NSNumber *passwordValid) {
      return [passwordValid boolValue] ? [UIColor greenColor] : [UIColor redColor];
  }]
 subscribeNext:^(UIColor *color) {
     passwordTextField.layer.borderColor=[color CGColor];
     passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
     confirmPasswordTextField.layer.borderColor=[color CGColor];
     confirmPasswordTextField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
 }];


RACSignal *signUpActiveSignal =
[RACSignal combineLatest:@[validEmailSignal, validPasswordSignal, validConfirmPasswordSignal]
                  reduce:^id(NSNumber *emailValid, NSNumber *passwordValid, NSNumber *confirmPasswordValid) {
                      return @([emailValid boolValue] && [passwordValid boolValue] && [confirmPasswordValid boolValue]);
                  }];


[signUpActiveSignal subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *signupActive) {

    NSLog(@"sign up button enabled : %hhd", [signupActive boolValue]);
    _signUpButton.enabled = [signupActive boolValue];
}];
```

Here, if I take only emailValid's value, it is sending 1 when valid. But if I include all three values, it always returns 0 even if all are valid.

Here are snap shots of the simulator:

[image]
[image]

I just wanted to enable "Sign up" button when all three fields are valid. I also want disable "Go" button on the keyboard till validation success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, two things:

You can use the `and` helper of `RACSignal` to make that signal reduction a little cleaner:

```
RACSignal *signUpActiveSignal = [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[validEmailSignal,
                                                            validPasswordSignal,
                                                            validConfirmPasswordSignal]] and];
```

You can also use the `RAC` macro to bind the `enabled` property (the only reason that the example code is using `subscribeNext` instead of `RAC` is that `CGColorRef` isn't of type `id`):

```
RAC(self.signUpButton, enabled) = signUpActiveSignal;
```

Now onto the reason this isn't working. Let's look at the calculations for the password fields:

```
RACSignal *validPasswordSignal = [passwordTextField.rac_textSignal map:^id(NSString *text) {
    return @([text isEqualToString:self.confirmPasswordTextField.text] && text.length > 5);
}];

RACSignal *validConfirmPasswordSignal = [confirmPasswordTextField.rac_textSignal map:^id(NSString *text) {
    return @([text isEqualToString:self.passwordTextField.text] && text.length > 5);
}];
```

Every time `passwordTextField`'s text changes, it compares it to  `confirmPasswordTextField`. But it only checks that they're the same when *`passwordTextField`* changes, *not* when `confirmPasswordTextField` changes. So let's imagine the following scenario, ignoring (for now) the length requirement:

```
------------------- initial state -------------------

           -------------
password: |             |   passwordValid: YES
           -------------

           -------------
 confirm: |             |   confirmValid: YES
           -------------

-------------- user types in a password --------------

           -------------
password: | asdf        |   passwordValid: NO
           -------------

           -------------
 confirm: |             |   confirmValid: YES (this will only recalculate when the confirm field changes, not when the password field changes)
           -------------


------- user types in the password confirmation -------

           -------------
password: | asdf        |   passwordValid: NO (this didn't recalculate because the contents of the password field didn't change)
           -------------

           -------------
 confirm: | asdf        |   confirmValid: YES
           -------------
```

Aha! So we need to recalculate when *either* of them changes. And, really, that should be a separate signal from the lengths:

```
RACSignal *passwordsMatch = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[passwordTextField.rac_textSignal,
                                                       confirmPasswordTextField.rac_textSignal]
                                              reduce:(NSString *password, NSString *confirm) {
                                                  return @([password isEqualToString:confirm]);
                                              }];

RACSignal *isPasswordLongEnough = [passwordTextField.rac_textSignal map:^(NSString *text) {
    return @(text.length >= 6);
}];
```

Then we can put it all together:

```
RACSignal *signUpActiveSignal = [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[validEmailSignal,
                                                            isPasswordLongEnough,
                                                            passwordsMatch]] and];
```

Which is great, because that's sort of how we think of it: "You can sign in when the email address is valid, the password you entered is long enough, and the password confirm field matches the password." Declarative!

Comment: It worked! thanks. One more thing, how can I disable the "Go" button in the keyboard and only enable if "signUpActiveSignal" is true?

Comment: @regeint To the best of my knowledge, that isn't possible. You can have the button disabled when the field is *empty* using `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically`, but that's the only thing you can do to it. Might want to search around a bit, but I've never heard of something like that.

Comment: oh, thanks anyway. I wish apple may add this feature in the future. :)